# How to search on Google and not have results be influenced by cookies/IP location etc

Tags: google-search

Is this possible? http://vanillaresults.com/ does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote myself a proxy script that makes a separate new connection to Google Search and only sends it the search requested (no cookies are passed through). Oh, and it passes the user agent through, because Google Search will not handle unknown user agents.

That solves the problem of cookies. But it doesn't solve the problem of IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Searchonymous**](https://github.com/MorbZ/Searchonymous) ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/searchonymous/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/searchonymous/onhfdppooafpnnigbmnpnnjmbajggekc?hl=en))  browser extension can help prevent info (cookie info, to be specific) from being tracked, and from being used to tailor search results by Google.

> Searchonymous helps to prevent your Google searches from tracking by Google or the NSA. When installed no tracking cookies are sent to Google while searching. This is done by blocking certain Google cookies (such as the PREF-ID) or generating randomized ones (which are worthless for tracking). Other cookies that just contain your search preferences will be allowed, so your preferences are preserved. You will stay logged in on other Google services such as Youtube or Gmail. It also removes ads and clutter from the Google main page that is normally shown when cookies are disabled.